# Conditional regex to use with sed having trouble

Tags: regex, bash, sed

Hi I am having trouble to understand why this regex:

```
(candy)?(?(1)A| is false)
```

for this String: `A candy is true is false` is not matching the `A`, and instead is matching  `is false`

What I'm really trying to do is, for example, if I have a *Windows* in this string:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) is false.
```

I want to substitute all this string to just `Windows` using sed command in Bash. If the string doesn't contain `Windows`, it's supposed to just replace with `-`.

The bash command I'm trying to use is:

```
sed -i 's/(?(?=Windows)("Mozilla.*)|(?!))/Windows/' accesslog.txt
```

Comment: First of all, `sed`'s POSIX regex flavor does not support [conditional constructs](https://www.regular-expressions.info/conditional.html). And what you want to do has nothing to do with this conditional construct. What is the expected behavior if the line contains no `Windows`?

Comment: That's not a valid RE in the dialect sed understands. (POSIX Basic; many versions also understand POSIX Extended with the `-E` option, but that's not an ERE either)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew if the String doesn't contain Windows, it's supposed to just replace with "-"

Comment: The bash command not working is:  `sed -i 's/(?(?=Windows)("Mozilla.*)|(?!))/Windows/' accesslog.txt` this the .txt file having the accesslog lines

Comment: Of course it does not, it contains 1) lookaheads, 2) conditional, 3) it is POSIX BRE, `|` is a literal char in this flavor. Please check common regex resource about POSIX regex differences from NFA regex flavors. Well, at least [this one](https://www.regular-expressions.info/posix.html).

Answer (score 1):

First of all, `sed`'s POSIX regex flavor does not support [conditional constructs](https://www.regular-expressions.info/conditional.html). What you want to do has nothing to do with regex conditional constructs as all they do is match further text depending on the previous group match, or text immediately before or after the current location.

You want something like

```sh
#!/bin/bash
s='Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) is false.
some other line'
sed 's/.*\(Windows\).*/\1/; t; s/.*/-/' <<< "$s"
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/ghPbFe). Output:

```
Windows
-
```

The `'s/.*\(Windows\).*/\1/; t; s/.*/-/'` command means:

- `s/.*\(Windows\).*/\1/` - replace the whole line that contains `Windows` (captured into Group 1 with a capturing group) with the Group 1 value
- `t` - jump to the end of the command  upon successful substitution
- `s/.*/-/` - else, replace the whole line with `-`.